# Create key array with dynamic array

Tags: php, arrays

For example user give me an array like this :

```
$input = ['countries', 'cities', 'towns'];
```

I want to create an array like this, i know what right side is :

```
$output["countries"]["cities"]["towns"] = "Downtown";
```

another example :

```
$input = ['cities', '0'];

$output["cities"][0] = "Nice";
```

I want to create a key / value array using the key given to me as a key.

I do not know the length of the array given to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hold a reference of the last array in a loop :

```
$input = ['countries', 'cities', 'towns'];
$output = [];
$ref = &$output;
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $ref[$value] = [];
    $ref = &$ref[$value];
}
$ref="Downtown";
print_r($output);
```

Will outputs :

```
Array
(
    [countries] => Array
        (
            [cities] => Array
                (
                    [towns] => Downtown
                )
        )
)
```

Your second example :

```
$input = ['cities', '0'];
$output = [];
$ref = &$output;
foreach ($input as $value) {
    $ref[$value] = [];
    $ref = &$ref[$value];
}
$ref="Nice";
print_r($output);
```

Will outputs :

```
Array
(
    [cities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nice
        )

)
```